# SQL Multiple select count statements in one query

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have data with no relation. Just need to count various columns from 3 tables and display them on the page as a view.

This is the code so far but doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(cars) AS A,
       (SELECT COUNT(boats) FROM tableBoats) AS B,
       (SELECT COUNT(trees) FROM tableTrees) AS C,
 FROM tableCars
```

Comment: What's the error you get and what database are you using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM (SELECT COUNT(cars) as A FROM tableCars) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(boats) as B FROM tableBoats) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(trees) as C FROM tableTrees) c
```

should do it.

Comment: That worked!!! THANKS. I am trying to accept answer but its telling me to wait 5 minutes. Ill do it after worK!

Comment: @user999690 You don't have to accept an answer quickly. When a question has not been answered yet, it motives people to answer it. Then you can have more than one solution to your problem :-)

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you have a table like here (`tableXxx` tables having a field named `xxx`), your query had a syntax error by having a comma after `AS C,`, without that comma, it works properly (at least using sqlite, because mssql is not working at sqlfiddle for me):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5fa6c/3

```
SELECT COUNT(cars) AS A,
       (SELECT COUNT(boats) FROM tableBoats) AS B,
       (SELECT COUNT(trees) FROM tableTrees) AS C
FROM tableCars
```

BTW, you could simplify your query to

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(cars ) FROM tableCars ) AS A,
       (SELECT COUNT(boats) FROM tableBoats) AS B,
       (SELECT COUNT(trees) FROM tableTrees) AS C
```

The other answers are also perfect :)

Comment: Thanks to that I've decreased loading time on 2 of pages by over 200%, and on another by 30%

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableCars) car_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableBoats) boat_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableTrees) tree_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on Luc M's response, which provides a single list, vs columns with separate values. 
You can imagine how useful this might be...

```
SELECT C.Accountnum as AccountNum, C.Address as Address, 'C' as Source 
From CustTable C 
Where C.AccountNum like '000%' 
Union All 
Select V.Accountnum as AccountNum, V.Name as Address, 'V' as Source 
from VendTable V 
Where V.AccountNum like 'A%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT 'Nb cars'  as description, COUNT(cars)  AS count_item FROM tableCars
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Nb boats' as description, COUNT(boats) AS count_item FROM tableBoats
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Nb tress' as description, COUNT(trees) AS count_item FROM tableTrees
) temp
```